# highlight text in html with javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight all the keywords (case insensitive) within a p tag programatically

if the keywords are

```
var keywords = "hello,thanks, goodbye" // this should be an array
<p>hello world</p>
```

hello should be highlighted in blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [jQuery highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin.

Once you have it loaded, you can just do something like this:

```
var words = "hello,thanks, goodbye";
var keywords = words.split(',');
for(var x = 0; x < keywords.length; x++) {
    $(selector).highlight($.trim(keywords[x]));
}
```

Where `selector` is what element in the document you want to look for. If you want it to be done to the entire page, just put `'body'`.

Answer (score -1):

For a lenient jQuery highlight plugin you may want to consider http://www.frightanic.com/2011/02/27/lenient-jquery-highlight-plugin-javascript/