# Javascript or jQuery for Adding Style to Phrases on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm applying a style to a certain phrase on our website over and over again.  Is there a way to search the page for instances of that phrase and apply that style automatically?

Example:

```
<div>
     This is what you get from <span class="comp">Company Name</span>. 
     We do all kinds of things here at <span class="comp">Company Name</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: So many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671574/highlight-text-in-html-with-javascript-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230714/jquery-how-to-highlight-certain-words-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at these questions:

- [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)
- [How to highlight certain words with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230714/jquery-how-to-highlight-certain-words-with-jquery)

Both of the top answers point to the [highlight plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for jQuery.

Comment: I used the highlight plugin.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

sure...
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text

```
$("div:contains('Conpany Name')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: That will style the entire div

Comment: As CMS said, that will style the entire div, and it would most likely be better to use .addClass("comp") rather than manually setting a new CSS style in this case.

Comment: oops... It was off the cuff to find the text, but I'm sure it wouldn't take much more to just style the text in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;

body.replace(/Company Name/g, '<span class="comp">Company Name</span>');
document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = body;
```

The above should get everything in the body and replace it with your span and that doesnt need jQuery.

Comment: I think you mean ('<span class="comp">Company Name</span>'); or escape the middle "s, as the current code would throw an error.

Comment: `<div title="Company Name are good!!">blah blah</div>` -> whoops. Don't process HTML with regex.Bonus: the innerHTML writeback also destroys any form data, event handlers and JS/jQuery references you have. Don't process HTML with regex.